# excel 2013 conditional formatting is forcing absolute

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use relative cell expression but when I do it automatically makes it absolute no matter what I try.

[before apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUsJM.png)

When I hit apply it changes the value to =$A$5

[after apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHnDw.png)

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the absolute reference in "Applies to" is **by design**. If you want to apply conditional formatting to multiple rows or columns, you will need to select all corresponding cells in "Applies to".
[image]

Any miunderstandings, please let me know.